# SonarQube 6 and Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sonarqube

Good day,

I am trying to setup `SonarQube 6` to work with an `Oracle 11G` database. I have created a blank schema and configured the `sonar.properties` file to point to the database mentioned. During the startup process, I can see that `sonarQube` has created the required tables but I get the following error:

> **org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException**  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.processBatch(Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.processAfter(Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doUpdate(ReuseExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:57)
>     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.insert(Unknown Source)

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Please share your code, see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The issue wasn't caused by any code I developed. I was setting up SonarQube on a cloud server connecting to an Oracle database instance. The error was being thrown when SonarQube was starting up pointing to an Oracle 11G database with ojdbc7.jar driver. This was resolved by using ojdbc8.jar instead.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was due to a bug in the oracle driver that I was using (version 7). Bug was fixed by oracle in version 8 as described here:

http://glennpaulley.ca/conestoga/2015/06/configuring-sonarqube-with-oracle-12c/

Specifically, the following was referenced to resolve:

> I opened a Chrome browser and tried to get to the SonarQube server’s home page. Alas, what I got was this:
>
> Fortunately, this null pointer exception problem with Oracle’s JDBC driver in method oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaDataColumnIndexes is a known issue and is fixed in version 12.1.0.2 of the Oracle JDBC drivers, which has just been released and can be found here. With the patched JDBC driver copied to the SonarQube /extensions directory, I now have a properly-working SonarQube server.

Comment: informations at the site you referrence seem good but when anybody needs to use this info in the future perhaps the reference won't exist on that address. So please put the related code here as text.